# Can games be played?

Tags: software-installation

Can I play games on Ubuntu ? Just want to know. And also I have a AMD Radeon graphics card but Ubuntu says I have Intel Haswell graphics ? :S

Comment: Sorry I think in asked 2 questions in one

Comment: Have you looked in "System settings -> Software & Updates" under "Additional Drivers" tab if drivers for AMD are listed (fglrx).

Answer (score 1):

You need to download AMD drivers for Linux from their site and install it.

> AMD Drivers http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

And yes there are games for Linux, you can download Steam and play a lot of games like CS:GO, War Thunder, Tomb Raider and many others.

> Steam download for Ubuntu http://store.steampowered.com/about/

But if you want to play for example League of Legends because there is no LOL for Linux you can simply install wine and install windows application under Linux. If you want more info just search in google for **WINE**

> How to install Wine: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: It would be much better to provide the actual commands to install these packages, all three are in the repos, downloading executables from websites will inevitably cause issues.